# How to read multiple excel sheet to store the content of excel sheet into database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

i write a code to read the content of excel sheet into database using property file..In my code i explicitly  passing  the excel file name,bt if suppose i want to procress multiple excel sheet,what can i do? how multiple excel sheet can b read n how can i save it in database?

Comment: you should share your code if you want our help

Answer (score 1):

First of all you save the EXCEL file as csv format.Then use following query for insert Data into database.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.csv' INTO TABLE db2.my_table;
```

You got my point?